# Configure Websocket for existing REST API - NodeJS, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to establish a continuous connection between my React APP and REST API. Backend is written in JAVA. Whenever new data is added in the DB, should get the updated data to my react APP. For this process, i'm using websockets. I have created connection between the client(React APP) and websocket.js(NodeJS)

`websocket.js` running in port 8000

```
const webSocketsServerPort = 8000;
const webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort);
console.log("Listening on Port 8000");

const wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
})

const clients = {};

// This code generates unique userid for everyuser.
const getUniqueID = () => {
  const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4();
};

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  var userID = getUniqueID();
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Recieved a new connection from origin ' + request.origin + '.');
  
  const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  clients[userID] = connection;
  console.log('connected - : ' + userID + ' in ' + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clients))
});
```

My React Component

```
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000');

componentDidMount() {
    client.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    };
}
```

My React APP is running is `localhost:3000`. The websocket connection is established.

Basically my data list API, where I'm getting the updated data is `http//server.com/getDataList` and connection through websocket like below does not seem to work

```
const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://server.com/getDataList:8000');
```

I also have `.ngnix.config` file on my React APP

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /share/nginx/html/;
        index  /share/nginx/html/index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

So how do I get continuous connection between my React APP through an existing REST API to get the updated data to my React APP, when a new data pushes to the DB using websockets, since i could get connection only on localhost

Comment: Typo: `ws://server.com/getDataList:8000` — The port number goes between the hostname and the path, not after the path.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is your own problem, but you don't seem to have provided a [mcve]. I don't know why you would have a different path for your live websocket service compared to your development one. You don't seem to understand that a REST API and a Websocket service are fundamentally different ways to transfer data (although they *can* run through the same HTTP server). Your question is asking about passing data through a websocket when data is added to a DB, but you haven't got any code in the question where data is added to a DB.

Comment: @Quentin I have limited understanding of Websockets. I am not aware of how data is added in the DB, since I have the API's which are exposed which fetches the data from the DB is what I think have enough information on the client end for the configuration for websocket

Comment: Need to know are there any backend configuration needed to require to understand and implement the websocket for client?

Comment: If you want to do something *when data is added to the DB* then you need to detect that event. Having REST APIs which pull data from the DB won't help you much with that (although you could poll the APIs and diff the results … which would be horribly inefficient)

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your time. understood on the API's limitations.